# Haskell Eq definition realizing a result

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I was reading the definition for the `Eq` typeclass in the Data library, and I'm confused. At what point is it realized that two values are equal or not equal. From what I see, it looks like they would just call each other ad infinitum.

It's defined as so:

```
class  Eq a  where
    (==), (/=)           :: a -> a -> Bool

    x /= y               = not (x == y)
    x == y               = not (x /= y)
```

Would somebody mind explaining where it realizes the `Bool` value? Are they even calling each other, or is something else going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That’s the default implementation of those methods, and yes, it is circular. If you use them as-is, you’ll loop:

```
data Foo = Foo
instance Eq Foo
```

```
> Foo == Foo
^CInterrupted
```

The circular definitions exist so you can implement `(==)` and get `(/=)` for free, or vice versa:

```
data Foo = Foo
instance Eq Foo where
  x == y = True
```

```
> Foo /= Foo
False
```

See also the [Ord](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Ord) class, which explains what the minimal complete definition is in that particular case.

Comment: So what happens when you use `deriving (Eq)`?

Comment: Wow, that is incredibly useful.

Comment: @Code-Guru: you can always see derived instances with `-ddump-deriv` GHC flag if you're curious

Comment: @Code-Guru The deriving instance tests that the two values have the same constructor and that the constructors are both populated by equal fields.

Comment: Note that for the latter check, it requires the fields to have an 'Eq' instance too.